# How to extract topographical data from a profile drawing

Tags: qgis, 3d, profile

I have what seems to be an uncommon problem: I have dozens of raster files containing profile drawings (x,z or y,z) and a raster map that shows their (x,y) extents. I want to be able to extract the topographical information from the profile drawings as vector data with an `elevation` attribute.

I'm currently using QGIS 3.16 because that's what I'm most comfortable with, but I also have a license for ArcGIS 10.7 (Desktop, not Pro) and am open to switching. My OS is Windows 10 Home.

Here's a mock example. I have the following profile drawing

[image: Example Profile Drawing]

whose extents are given by the thick dotted line of the following (georeferenced) map

[image: Example Map]

At the very least, I want to create a vector layer with 14 points (4 for layer 'B', 4 for 'C', 6 for 'D'). Each point should have an `elevation` attribute and a `layer_name` attribute.

For the example image shown above, it wouldn't be hard to do this manually (e.g., calculate the location of every point myself, put the coordinates in a csv file, and create the vector data from csv). However, this would be extremely tedious and error-prone with my dozens of real-world profile drawings, and I would prefer to develop a workflow that allows me to trace the raster image directly.

If you are wondering why on earth I would want to do this at all, it's because I'm working with legacy archaeological data and am trying to create 3D models so I can model the volumes of soil moved to create an ancient structure. Profile drawings are often the only way to get elevation data from old archaeological publications.